# updating eclipse gives errors

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to update Eclipse for Java EE and it gives me following errors, any idea how can I resolve it. I am using eclipse

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857

    An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
    session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.jcraft.jsch,0.1.46.v201205102330
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.persistence,2.0.5.v201212031355
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.servlet,3.0.0.v201112011016
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.servlet.jsp,2.2.0.v201112011158
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.ant,1.8.3.v201301120609
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.commons.lang,2.6.0.v201205030909
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ant.launching,1.0.200.v20120530-1204
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ant.ui,3.5.301.v20121210-210948
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.compare.win32,1.0.200.v20120914-154749
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans,1.2.200.v20120523-1955
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.externaltools,1.0.100.v20120521-2012
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.filesystem.win32.x86,1.1.300.v20120522-1137
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.net,1.2.200.v20120914-093638
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.net.win32.x86,1.0.100.v20120522-1148
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.resources.win32.x86,3.5.100.v20120522-1137
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility,3.2.200.v20120521-2346
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry,3.5.101.v20130108-163257
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cvs,1.2.1.v201302041200
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity,1.2.7.v201302060508
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.apache.derby,1.0.103.v201212070447
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.db.generic.ui,1.0.2.v201211200622
    No repository found containing:
```

I have configured eclipse with ADT for android development.

Please advise what's happening here ?

Thanks,
Ahmed

Comment: Eclipse ADT is deprecated. Use Android Studio.

Comment: Which update site are you using? AT this point, it should be Mars ( http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars/ ) and shouldn't be seeking such outdated versions.

Comment: you could try to check contact all update sites button when installing

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to try ADT, In Window -> Preferences -> Install/Update -> Available Software Sites, find url to ADT Plugin and change https to http. When you finalize update operation revert changed url to https. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is telling you that Eclipse Indigo (3.7) is too old for the code you are trying to install.

You need to move to a newer version of Eclipse (Eclipse Mars (4.5) is the current release).

However Google are dropping support for Android development using Eclipse so you may want to look at Android Studio.